# Possible to manually force update to latest Wordpress?

Tags: dashboard

I built a basic site as a favour to a friend several years ago which I was recently asked to update. Upon logging in, I get the dashboard sidebar but nothing else — the page itself is blank (see attached screenshot).

[image: Blank page in admin dashboard]

I don't know why this is, but the site is definitely running an ancient version of Wordpress. Is there a way to manually update it to the latest version, given that I cannot update it via the dashboard?

Comment: Normally it should work automatically, for settings take a look here. A good explanation about how/what to do[Chip Bennett explains](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120082).
Please take also a look at the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Disabling_Automatic_Background_Updates) and/or [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2013/10/25/the-definitive-guide-to-disabling-auto-updates-in-wordpress-3-7/)

Answer (score 0):

This was actually a bug in the version of WP running on the site. The accepted answer on [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127427/how-to-fix-empty-dashboard-issue-in-wordpress) gave me the solution.