# Empty Dashboard in Wordpress

Tags: dashboard

I have the most updated version of wordpress for my site on [private tutors](https://www.findtutorsnearme.com/). Last week I upgraded Apache and PHP on our production server. Afterwards the dashboard refused to work. When a user logs in, a blank dashboard appears. A menu with links is still present, but none of the links work, so one cannot create new posts etc. In the page source I see the following message:

```
Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: WP_Screen::$this in blog/wp-  admin/includes/screen.php on line 706
```

There were no changes to WordPress configuration made and no new plugins installed. What the heck did I do wrong and can anyone please help me?

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest version of WordPress? Because there is no line 706 in `wp-admin/includes/screen.php`. In that file there is only 234 lines.

Comment: If you're still on version 3.3.1, sounds like this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/127486/84643

Answer (score 0):

***I know this post is old but the right answer may help someone else.***
Sounds like you are still using WordPress 3.* because it has a bug causing the issue. You need to be sure you're using the right version of Apache and PHP as required by the copy of WordPress version you just upgraded to.

You may also replace your current core WordPress with the latest 5.* manually in the cpanel. Check out

- https://en-gb.wordpress.org/about/requirements/
- [How to fix empty dashboard issue in WordPress?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127427/how-to-fix-empty-dashboard-issue-in-wordpress)